# Enter credentials then post JSON to api java

Tags: java, json, spring, post, basic-authentication

I have been trying to figure out a way to post a JSON to a external api. The issue is a don't want to hardcode the username and password but rather have it be used by anyone who has valid credentials to the API.I have code that works for hardcoded credentials but I want the user to enter the the username and password per request. I want to use the basic auth browser dialogue to capture the credentials then post JSON but I can't figure it out.

here is my current code

```
public class RestService {
    String Username="admin";
    String Password="pass";

  public String createPost() throws AuthenticateException,ClientHandlerException {

String url = "https://someapi.net/rest/api/2/issue/";

Client client = Client.create ();

client.addFilter (new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(Username, Password));
WebResource webResource= client.resource(url);
//--INPUT is formatted a bit different In my app but I just can't show it
String input = "{
    "fields": {
       "project":
       {
          "key": "TEST"
       },
       "summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.",
       "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
       "issuetype": {
          "name": "Bug"
       }
   }
}"

ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class,input);
string output = response.getEntity(String.Class)
```

I found this and was told it might work but I'm not sure where I enter that into my code.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username+":"+password).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));  //Java 8
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+encoded);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to create an Jira issue with basic authentication by using Jersey Client API, then you can pass the credential in header as follows:

```
String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json")
        .header("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded) // put the credential in header
        .post(ClientResponse.class,input);
```

Comment: yes I am trying to create a jira issue but i want to remove the hard coded password inside and have the browser prompt to enter password

Comment: this isn't any different from what I was doing before. I seems like

Comment: @NormX What did you mean "I want the user to enter the the username and password per request"? If you can get the credential provided by user, it is not hard coded. So the question is how you got the credential?

Comment: so username and password strings are defined but I wanted to know if I left the values blank is there a way for the browser to prompt me to enter the credentials. similar to this https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj8k_zmvPnlAhXMuVkKHRgpBKUQMwhCKAEwAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F34434235%2Fnative-browser-login-prompt&psig=AOvVaw3ZXwfgjH5zZYZ35HFVx_T9&ust=1574362855527183&ictx=3&uact=3

Comment: @NormX Yes, there are many ways to achieve this such as you can redirect users to your login page if they are not authenticated. After they logging in, just take their username and password as credential for Jira.

Comment: okay that what I wanted to say in my question I guess I should of said that to start off with im trying to figure out was to use spring securities login page for that specific url and get the credentials and use it for the post call